# Analogue for connectedness of planar graphs

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I know that any planar triangulation is $4$-connected if and only if it has no separating triangle. I was wondering if there exists a similar analogue or result for perhaps planar quadrangulations or planar graphs where all faces are incident to $n$ vertices for $n\geq 4$? I have not been able to find anything thus far.

Answer (score 1):

No.

In fact, in planar quadrangulations, *no* $2$ or $3$ vertex cut can correspond to a cycle ($2$ because the graph is simple, $3$ because it's triangle-free as a result of being bipartite).

For $n\geq 4$, you can always find a vertex $u$ of degree $2$ (double-count the edges and use Euler's formula $V-E+F = 2$). The two vertices adjacent to $u$ certainly cannot be the vertices of a cycle - they cannot even be adjacent!

Comment: Can there exist subgraphs in these graphs that do not have a vertex of degree 2?

Comment: For quadrangulations - yes, and these can be quadrangulations themselves. For graphs with larger faces, yes, but these subgraphs will themselves have at least one "smaller" face.